# CSV Importing With Rails, Postgres, and Sidekiq

Tags: postgresql, csv, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq

I'm building a customer management system using Rails that requires CSV files containing customer information to be imported into/diffed with a Postgres database.  I'm hosting the application on Heroku.  I moved the database to the background with Sidekiq but need advice on where to upload the file to in the first place for importing.  Is hosting the file on S3 really the best solution or is there a simpler solution without using a third party storage service?  The application will be used daily but up 10 employees and the larges CSV file being upload is around 100,000 rows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I do think S3 is the best solution

We faced same problem at Storemapper (we use Resque instead of Sidekiq, but that's not a problem). The limiting factor here is the Heroku request timeout. You only have 30s to finish your upload to Heroku, which put hard limit on how big your csv can be. This is where S3 come. Basically what we do is:

1. User upload csv directly to S3 via javascript, bypassing our app server on Heroku.
2. Once the upload complete, the javascript makes a request to app server that will launch background worker, telling the worker where the file is at S3
3. The worker download the csv from s3, then process it as necessary

I found carrierwave_direct gem to be very helpful for step 1 and 2. For step 3, I use smarter_csv gem. Checkout our complete story here: 
https://tylertringas.com/very-large-csv-import-in-rails-on-heroku/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response @taufiq-muhammadi.  I was actually using you and Tyler's story already!  It was the Javascript server bypass part that I was missing.  I found a [Heroku sourced explanation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails) that was very helpful and used JqueryFileUpload instead of carrierwave_direct.  As a bonus it outlines a nice css progress bar to go along with file upload.  Thanks again!

Comment: nice! I didn't know JQueryFileUpload. Glad it works out!

Comment: Hey @Taufiq, could you answer a question for me? In the Storemapper story, Tyler mentions "fetching the file from s3 and processing it." I'm using the AWS/S3 api to access the file but should I access it directly from S3 or save it somewhere in my DB or application and then process it?  As it is now, my workers are processing it directly from S3 and it's failing with larger files.

Comment: Sorry I just saw this @crmmmc .Why do they the workers fail exactly?
What I did is just download the file from s3 and save it in the temporary folder. Then we open the temp file with SmarterCSV in chunks, to avoid loading all rows into memory